# Js or Jquery: Get url and replace url to change language

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make text link to change language

> English: http://example.com/
>
> Japan: http://jp.example.com/

When visitor on a page A (English)

> example: http://example.com/A

I want make a text link, when visitor click , visitor go to Japan language with link like:

> http://jp.example.com/A

I really thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

call following method as onclick="switchLanguage()"

```
function switchLanguage() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('jp.example.com') != -1)
       window.location.href = url.replace('jp.example.com', 'example.com');
    else 
       window.location.href = url.replace('example.com', 'jp.example.com');
}
```

Comment: Sory, i do not display full i want. If i have three or four language. I need a text link for a language. If i have four language, i need display four text link

Comment: so add a parameter in the function, write switch case. get the relative url and append into your language specific base url .

Comment: Thank for your help. I will test your code and reply you result

Comment: I tested and it work. I really thank you a lot. Dear Bilal Siddiqui!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your links will be inside

```
<div id="language-container">
</div>
```

In this case, let's ensure that we have a `function` like

```
function getLanguageLinks() {
    let languages = {
        "jp": "Japanese",
        "": "English",
        "ge": "German",
        "hu": "Hungarian"
    };
    var links = [];
    for (var key in languages) {
        links.push('<p><a href="http://${key}${key.length ? "." : ""}example.com">${languages[key]}</a></p>');
    }
    document.getElementById("language-container") = links.join("");
}
```

and you are calling it in your `body` tag:

```
<body onload="getLanguageLinks()">
    <!-- Some HTML -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I will test your code and reply you result